How can I find the origin of a rejected promise
Recently, we saw a steep increase of errors titled Event CustomEvent (type=unhandledrejection) captured as promise rejection in Sentry. Based on the research so far, it looks like a promise gets rejected somewhere in the code, but we have not yet been able to find where this happens.
I've already added below piece of code to log a trace entry with some information about the rejected event, but apparently the reason is undefined. I know there is also a promise property on the listener argument, but I don't know how to get any useful information from that object. Is it possible to determine the source of a promise, and if so, how?
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', ({ reason }) => {
  ErrorManagement.addTrace({
    data: { reason },
    level: 'info',
    message: 'unhandledrejection caught',
    category: 'error',
  });
});

Update
Attempted to use window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', console.error) which did worked as intended, but unfortunately did not enclose more information than already was available in my own handler.
Also attempted to monkey-patch the CustomEvent constructor as shown below, inspired by the comments. When testing in console by invoking window.dispatch(new CustomEvent('unhandledrejection')) the stack appeared, but on production it does not show on the incoming events. I assume this is caused by the CustomEvent being created in another way, though I'm not versed enough in Javascript to say for sure.
class CustomEventWithStack extends CustomEvent<any> {
  stack?;

  constructor(type: string, eventInitDict?: CustomEventInit) {
    super(type, eventInitDict);
    if (type === 'unhandledrejection') {
      this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
    }
  }
}
CustomEventWithStack.prototype = CustomEvent.prototype;
CustomEventWithStack.prototype.constructor = CustomEventWithStack;
CustomEvent = CustomEventWithStack;

Update 2
Further attempts with monkey-patching:
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (event) => {
  ErrorManagement.addTrace({
    data: {
      reason: event.reason,
      stack: (event.promise as PromiseWithStack<any>).stack,
    },
    level: 'info',
    message: 'unhandledrejection caught',
    category: 'error',
  });
});

class PromiseWithStack<T> extends Promise<T> {
  stack = new Error().stack;

  constructor(executor: (resolve: any, reject: any) => void) {
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      executor(resolve, (reason: any) => {
        if (reason === undefined) {
          reject({ stack: new Error().stack });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

window.Promise = PromiseWithStack;
const originalFetch = fetch;
window.fetch = (...args) => new PromiseWithStack((resolve, reject) => {
  originalFetch(...args).then(resolve, reject);
});

Interestingly, this threw another error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stack'). This prompted me to further check the contents of the incoming event in the event listener:
data: {
  reason: event.reason,
  eventClass: event.constructor.name,
  promiseType: typeof event.promise,
  promiseClass: event.promise?.constructor.name,
},

Result:
{
  eventClass: CustomEvent,
  promiseType: undefined
}

So that leads me to another question: how is it possible that a CustomEvent ended up in the 'unhandledrejection' event listener? I realize this is very different from my original question and I'm not sure what the policy on that is. If I need to make a new question, please let me know.

you could probably use an error stack trace to trace the error in the stack

@JaromandaX do you have a suggestion for how to do so? Inside the event listener, I only have access to a PromiseRejectionEvent, which has no Error object property. I was considering throwing and catching an error within the event listener, but that would show the event listener as the source.

window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', console.error) then watch the console - I don't know if that will help (hence why it is a comment not an answer)

Do you remember a bluebird library used back in the days? What they basically did, is monkey-patched the promise with some additional functionality. I would assume, just for the debugging purposes, you could monkey patch your promise to return a trace where the promise was called. Let me know if you need more details on that. The problem would be that it will work only with the libraries and code that used global Promise object only.

The idea is to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zdgLnvxy/
Try it out without monkey-patch: you won't see any origin
Then with monkey-patch: it will throw you a stack trace where it was called from. Should at least serve as temporary debugging helper. T

Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried the console.error approach and another inspired by the monkey-patching, but unfortunately to no avail. See original question for outcomes of those

Just check your code for every promise that is created/returned and attach a catch handler to each that logs all you need to know to find that spot back, and have it re-trigger the same error.

A consequence of your Promise redefinition is that all rejections with defined reason are ignored. Do you really intend that?

@HeikoTheißen Nope, it seems I made a mistake in implementing the suggested approach, thanks for the heads-up! I've removed monkey-patches for now, since I don't think they will lead to any new insights

"I realize this is very different from my original question and I'm not sure what the policy on that is" - yes, please ask a separate question about that

Btw I don't get what this stuff has to do with CustomEvents at all, why would anything fire those - or even CustomEventWithStack instances? It seems what you want is ErrorManagement.addTrace(… reason: event.reason, errorStack: event.reason?.stack, constructionStack: event.promise?.stack …).

Have you also tried monkey-patching the Promise, as suggested by Pavlo Sobochuk? The following monkey-patch records the stack when someone rejects a promise without reason.


const ecmaPromise = Promise;
Promise = class extends ecmaPromise {
  constructor(executor) {
    super(function(resolve, reject) {
      executor(resolve, function(reason) {
        if (reason === undefined)
          reason = {
            stack: new Error().stack
          };
        reject(reason);
      });
    });
  }
}
const ecmaFetch = fetch;
fetch = function(...args) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ecmaFetch(...args).then(resolve, reject);
  });
};
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', console.error);
fetch("https://httpbin.org/delay/1")
.then(function() {
  throw undefined;
});



Note I also monkey-patched the fetch function, because this would otherwise still return unpatched ecmaPromises. Perhaps there are more promise-returning native functions that must be handled in the same way.

Maybe also create a new Error() in the constructor itself, not just in the reject function, to get the stack trace of the code that created the promise not only the code that rejected it

Thanks! This did not solve the problem itself, but I did manage to take another step towards a fix. See original question for an update

The same issue appears on my Sentry dashboard. After searching for "unhandledrejection" in Chrome DevTools, I identified that the CustomEvent is most likely created by scripts initiated by gpt.js (Google Publisher Tag)

